# antMatcher().PermitAll is not working as expected

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to exclude the sub part of url, i.e my url is /eval/v2/save/public/image, this pattern is authenticated, but there is URI which i want to exclude and that URI is fall under the /eval/v2/**.
I have tried the below configuration, but still my custom `OncePerRequestFilter` invoked for the `save/public/images`, I have tried various solution from the stackoverflow itself but none of them worked for me.

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        StringBuffer sb = constuctAntMatcher();
//      http.headers().httpStrictTransportSecurity().includeSubDomains(true).maxAgeInSeconds(_MAX_AGE_IN_SEC);
        return http.csrf().disable().cors().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/eval/v1/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/save/public/image").permitAll()
                .and().formLogin().disable() // Disable default login page
                .httpBasic().disable().addFilterBefore(userIdAuthenticationFilter(), DisableEncodeUrlFilter.class)
                .build();
    }
```

I know i am making mistake, but the thing is i am unable to figure it out, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to set permit all before the authenticated:

```java
  return http
             .csrf().disable()
             .cors().disable()
             .authorizeRequests()
                 .antMatchers("/save/public/image").permitAll()
                 .antMatchers("/eval/v1/**").authenticated()
```

Comment: I have tired that too, but not working, i got the logger statements `Authorized filter invocation [POST /save/public/image] with attributes [permitAll]`, but on the contrary, my custom authentication filter invoked, I also toggled the breakpoint in my controller, but that not being hit, i am keep getting 401

Comment: One more thing this URI is having multipart/form-data content-type and I am struggling with that, that's why I want to exclude that uri

Comment: not public it is fall under the pattern `/eval/v2/**`, it is sub part of the URI, I want to exclude `/eval/v2/save/public/image`, except this I want to authenticate the rest of the URL

Comment: so why you are not using the whole uri /eval/v1/save/public/image

Comment: is it require to pass the entire uri?